# Insert weekly dates starting fridays

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to insert weekly dates in my table, the start date is always on Fridays and the end date is always on thursday. I'm using this code :

```
 CREATE TABLE WEEK AS
  WITH generator AS (
   SELECT DATE '2015-01-02' + LEVEL - 1 dt
     FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= DATE '2016-01-21' - DATE '2015-01-02' + 1
           )
    SELECT to_char(dt, 'YYYY "SEM"IW') "KEY",
       dt "DATE_START",
       least(next_day(dt - 1, to_char(DATE '2015-01-08', 'DAY')),
            last_day(dt)) "DATE_END"
 FROM generator
WHERE to_char(dt, 'D') = to_char(DATE '2015-01-02', 'D');
```

The code is working for weeks on the same month, but if I have a starting date on a month and the finish date on the next month, there's no data inserting in my table.
For example :

```
Date_ START | DATE_END

29-05-2015  | 31-05-2015     
05-06-2015  | 11-05-2015
```

Instead of 31-05-2015 I should have 04-06-2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following is what you're after:

```
with generator as (select     date '2015-05-29' + (level - 1)*7 dt
                   from       dual
                   connect by level <= (date '2016-01-21' - date '2015-05-29')/7 + 1)
select to_char(dt, 'YYYY "SEM"IW') "KEY",
       dt "DATE_START",
       dt + 6 "DATE_END"
from   generator;

KEY        DATE_START DATE_END  
---------- ---------- ----------
2015 SEM22 2015-05-29 2015-06-04
2015 SEM23 2015-06-05 2015-06-11
2015 SEM24 2015-06-12 2015-06-18
2015 SEM25 2015-06-19 2015-06-25
<snip>
2016 SEM01 2016-01-08 2016-01-14
2016 SEM02 2016-01-15 2016-01-21
```

This is assuming that the dates you have specified in the generator subquery have already been determined to be a Friday. Otherwise you could use something like `trunc(<date> - 4, 'iw') + 4` or `trunc(<date> + 3, 'iw') + 4` (depending on whether you want the previous or next Friday to be included for the date specified) to make sure that the seed date is definitely a Friday.

Comment: Thank you! I have all the dates I want with your code

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe just an alternative you can try analytical function here. But as
>   suggested by Boniest "just adding days" will be better approach. Have
>   fun

```
WITH generator AS
  (SELECT DATE '2015-01-02' + LEVEL - 1 dt
  FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= DATE '2016-01-21' - DATE '2015-01-02' + 1
  )
--  select * from generator;
SELECT TO_CHAR(dt, 'YYYY "SEM"IW') "KEY",
  dt "DATE_START",
  lead(dt) over (ORDER BY (dt)) -1 "End Date"
FROM generator
WHERE TO_CHAR(dt, 'D') = TO_CHAR(DATE '2015-01-02', 'D');

----------------------------------OUTPUT-----------------------------------------
**KEY       DATE_START  End Date**
2015 SEM18  05/01/2015  05/07/2015
2015 SEM19  05/08/2015  05/14/2015
2015 SEM20  05/15/2015  05/21/2015
2015 SEM21  05/22/2015  05/28/2015
2015 SEM22  05/29/2015  06/04/2015

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```